# Apply styling to certain items in a list in Vue

Tags: vue.js

how should I go about applying an attribute to a class for styling only for certain elements in a list? It will be clearer in the example below:

```
<u-col
    v-for="(item, i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :class="classNames.viewport"
>

data () {
    return {
        classNames: {
            viewport: "col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-6 d-flex justify-content-center"
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `i` only goes from 0-3. Currently every `item` in `v-for` has the class `viewport` for styling. What I am hoping to achieve is to only apply an additional margin style `mb-3` if `i` is greater than 1.

ie, the `viewport` becomes `"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-6 d-flex justify-content-center mb-3"` for items with i > 1, while `viewport` does not contain `mb-3` for items with i < 1.

I thought about using a `v-for` and `v-if` together but I believe it is not a good practice to do so, https://www.codecheef.org/article/dont-use-v-if-with-v-for-elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `:class` bind, you can check `i` and add `mb-3` to class when `i > 1`:

```js
<u-col
    v-for="(item, i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :class="classNames.viewport + (i > 1 ? ' mb-3' : '')"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
:class="`${classNames.viewport} ${i > 1 ? 'mb-3' : ''}`"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vue's [Class and Style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) and pass it an object.

```
<u-col
    v-for="(item, i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :class="{
        'col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-6 d-flex justify-content-center': true,
        'mb-3': i > 1,
    }"
/>
```